# How to resolve latency when connecting to MySQL?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have 2 VM's in the same machine, one running Apache, the other running MySQL.

When trying to connect from Apache to MySQL it takes 5 seconds for the console to come up.

When attempting to connect from Apache to an external MySQL, it works in less than 1/4 of a second.

How can I debug this? Could this be routing? I am accessing via IP, same network, same segment, etc.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

My money's on name resolution; the server's trying (and failing) to do a reverse DNS lookup on the private IP address that the connection's coming from.

Try the `skip-name-resolve` option.

Comment: Good suggestion... but it is already set...   I also noticed the same latency with SSH access.. so it must be networking.. but not sure where...

Comment: @smorhaim SSH will exhibit the same issue with an IP that won't resolve to a name.  Try adding an entry to the hosts file to circumvent and rule out name resolution issues.

Comment: The solution was adding an entry in the target machine hosts file as suggested :)  post it as an answer, so I can mark it as the winner. thanks.

Comment: @smorhaim: the correct answer is the answer.  the `hosts` suggestion in the comment is a hack but not a solution.